# Declare bind variable in the Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to try to execute this query via Oracle SQL Developer, but I always got the error message which is

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

```sql
DEFINE po_header_ids VARCHAR(1000) := '1,2,3';

    SELECT 
        PHA.SEGMENT1
    FROM 
        PO.PO_HEADERS_ALL       PHA
    WHERE     1=1
        AND (
            :po_header_ids = 0 OR 
            :po_header_ids IS NULL OR
            PHA.PO_HEADER_ID IN (
                SELECT regexp_substr(:po_header_ids,'[^,]+',1,level)
                FROM dual CONNECT BY
                regexp_substr(:po_header_ids ,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
            )
        )
```

[parameters which are entered in the oracle sql deverloper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA68q.png)

Can someone tell me which part is wrong?

Thank you.

Here's the query that I executed successfully and the data type of the `PO_HEADER_ID`

[PO_HEADER_ID Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diT2O.png)

```sql
DEFINE po_header_ids varchar(1000);
SELECT regexp_substr(:po_header_ids,'[^,]+',1,level) 
FROM dual CONNECT BY
regexp_substr(:po_header_ids,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
```

[Output of the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOMrQ.png)

Comment: "Invalid number" is related to datatypes. Could you post PO_HEADERS_ALL table **description** and several sample rows (that illustrate the problem)?

Comment: PHA.PO_HEADER_ID does probably include something that is not an integer.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, the data type of `PO_HEADERS_ALL`  is `NUMBER`. And I have updated the post to see if you can get a better understanding to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DEFINE` declares a substituition variable which will be prefixed by `&` in the code and is processed in the client application (i.e. in SQL Developer) as if a find-replace occurs on the statement.
- `VARIABLE` declares a bind-variable which will be prefixed by `:` in the code and is processed by the SQL engine on the server.

You also need to change: `:po_header_ids = 0` to `:po_header_ids = '0'` as the bind variable is a string and not a number.

So you want:

```sql
VARIABLE po_header_ids VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
  :po_header_id := '1,2,3';
END;
/

SELECT PHA.SEGMENT1
FROM   PO.PO_HEADERS_ALL       PHA
WHERE  :po_header_ids = '0'
OR     :po_header_ids IS NULL
OR     PHA.PO_HEADER_ID IN (
         SELECT TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(:po_header_ids,'[^,]+',1,level))
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY
                regexp_substr(:po_header_ids ,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
       );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=751f13d0b32051f9e7944662fe42e8b3)*

Comment: Hi, it seems that `DEFINE` and `VARIABLE` are not the problem. I still get the same error which is `invalid number` while executing the query that you provided. But thanks for telling me the differences between these two.

Comment: @Casey Updated, it is the filter `:po_header_ids = 0` comparing a string to a number that is an issue.